# Angular2-jwt AuthHttp request not called

Tags: angular, jwt, ionic2

I've been following [this guide](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/02/18/ionic-2-authentication-how-to-secure-your-mobile-app-with-jwt/) to set up JWT authentication in an Ionic 2 app. The login side of things is working absolutely fine, but when I try to use the AuthHttp class, no request is made and nothing displays in Chrome's `network` tab, or on the server side.

I have the following in my app.ts file:

```
import 'es6-shim';
import {App, IonicApp, Platform, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {AuthData} from './providers/auth-data';
import {UserData} from './providers/user-data';


@App({
    templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(AuthHttp, {
            useFactory: (http) => {
                return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
            },
            deps: [Http]
        }),
        AuthData,
        UserData
    ],
    config: {
        apiURL: 'http://localhost:9000'
    } // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
```

and then in user-data.ts I have this:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {Config, Storage, LocalStorage, Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AuthHttp, JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

/**
 * @name UserData
 * @description
 * Provider for any user related data.
 */
@Injectable()
export class UserData {

  apiURL: string;
  contentHeader: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  error: string;
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  local: Storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);
  storage: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(
    public authHttp: AuthHttp,
    private config: Config,
    private events: Events,
    private http: Http
  ) {
    this.apiURL = config.get('apiURL');
    let token = this.local.get('id_token')._result;
    if (token) {
      this.user = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
    }
  }

  getUser() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

      this.authHttp.get(this.apiURL+'/api/users/me', {
        headers: this.contentHeader
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          resolve('test');
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );

    });
  }

}
```

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong and if I'm missing something? I have gone through the angular2-jwt documentation lots of times and everything looks OK to me.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

If I do `console.log(this.authHttp)` inside the `getUser()` function, it logs the following:

```
AuthHttp {http: Http, _config: Object, tokenStream: Observable}
```

Comment: do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Nope, no errors at all which I found strange. I can `console.log(this.authHttp)` and it displays code too so it's definitely set.

Comment: Probably the same issue as mine  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343576/no-requests-being-dispatched-while-using-authhttp), though I managed to figure out ,that in my case it was due to the missing token. I have changed the default 'id_token' name to 'token' and the authHttp service couldn't find it  (even though I explicitly defined it in the authConfig). So when I changed it back, everything started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the perfect solution, but I noticed that in [this similar guide](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-and-auth0/) from Ionic they specify the angular2-jwt version as 0.1.6. Downgraded to this version and it works OK!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forget to specify the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the `providers` attribute of your application:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
(...)

@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(AuthHttp, {
        useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);
        },
        deps: [Http]
    }),
    AuthData,
    UserData
  ],
  config: {
     apiURL: 'http://localhost:9000'
  } // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
```

**Edit**

You only need to import the `Headers` class:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

Comment: Hi Thierry, unfortunately even with that in place it's still doing the same thing

Comment: You also forgot to import the `Headers` class ;-)

Comment: `HTTP_PROVIDERS` are defined before `AuthHttp`?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with what I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Recent updates to angular2-jwt should work fine with the latest Ionic 2 release. Can you check this repo and let me know if it works for you? :) https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-ionic2-samples

Edit: Link updated